# Hide or disable past dates on JDateChooser

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jdatechooser

I want to disable or hide or make the past dates in JDateChooser not selectable. How can I make this? I've tried to use `.setSelectableDateRange` but it doesn't work. I also tried `.setMinSelectableDate()` but still no luck. I don't know but netbeans doesn't seem to know those because those doesn't show up in code suggestions. I'm using it like this:

```
public void dateset() {
    jDateChooser1.getCalendar(). //What to put here? It doesn't have .setSelectableRange
}
```

I only tried the one that I've found on this one: [How to show only date after the date of today in JCalendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10021565/how-to-show-only-date-after-the-date-of-today-in-jcalendar)

I think that post was already outdated. Please help.

Comment: in most of Java Calendars is possible to determine Special Days

Comment: what do you mean Special Days?

Comment: for example hollydays,

Comment: You may want to take a look to [How to disable or highlight the dates in java calendar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18820257/how-to-disable-or-highlight-the-dates-in-java-calendar). The way on how dates are evaluated is explained there. It has to do with `IDateEvaluator` interface which is intended to validate if a date is special or invalid. JCalendar library provides an implemantation called `MinMaxDateEvaluator` which allows selecting a date in a defined range. Hope it be helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here:

```
jDateChooser1.getCalendar().
```

You're trying to set date's boundaries to a [java.util.Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) object which is not possible. Maybe you're confused with [getJCalendar()](http://max-server.myftp.org/jcalendar/ibuild/dist/doc/api/com/toedter/calendar/JDateChooser.html#getJCalendar%28%29) which returns a [JCalendar](http://max-server.myftp.org/jcalendar/ibuild/dist/doc/api/com/toedter/calendar/JCalendar.html) object:

```
jDateChooser1.getJCalendar().setMinSelectableDate(new Date()); // sets today as minimum selectable date
```

Note you can set minimum selectable date directly on date chooser:

```
jDateChooser1.setMinSelectableDate(new Date()); // sets today as minimum selectable date
```

Inspecting `JDateChooser` source code you can see this method is just forwarded to the `JCalendar` object:

```
public class JDateChooser extends JPanel implements ActionListener,
        PropertyChangeListener {

    protected IDateEditor dateEditor;
    protected JCalendar jcalendar;

    ...

    public void setMinSelectableDate(Date min) {
        jcalendar.setMinSelectableDate(min);
        dateEditor.setMinSelectableDate(min);
    }

    ...
}
```

You may also want to take a look to [How to disable or highlight the dates in java calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20753026/1795530) for a better understanding on [IDateEvaluator](http://max-server.myftp.org/jcalendar/ibuild/dist/doc/api/index.html?com/toedter/calendar/IDateEditor.html) interface which is actually the key on this whole date validation matter.

Answer (score 0):

Try this example..

```
package chooseyourdate;

import com.toedter.calendar.JCalendar;
import com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooser;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class MainFrame extends JFrame {

    private JDateChooser chooser;

    public MainFrame() {
        JCalendar calendar = new JCalendar(GregorianCalendar.getInstance());
        chooser = new JDateChooser(calendar, new Date(), "dd.MM.yy", null);
        GregorianCalendar cal = (GregorianCalendar)GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
        // set the max date
        cal.set(2015, 10, 10);
        // MinDate is the current Date
        // MaxDate you can set in the GregorianCalendar object
        chooser.setSelectableDateRange(new Date(), cal.getTime());
        chooser.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                // to something...
            }
        });
        this.setSize(new Dimension(800, 600));

        this.getContentPane().add(chooser, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```