# How to pop-up error in java swing to check whether the check-in date in hotel should be earlier than check-out date?

Tags: java, swing, date, datepicker

I have following screenshot from jswing application. [image: JswingDate]

Here, I have written as such to select date from the date picker -

```
//CheckIn Date
JDateChooser dateChooser = new JDateChooser();
dateChooser.setBounds(177, 136, 149, 22);
frame.getContentPane().add(dateChooser);

//CheckOut Date
JDateChooser dateChooser_1 = new JDateChooser();
dateChooser_1.setBounds(177, 136, 149, 22);
frame.getContentPane().add(dateChooser_1);
```

Now, How to write the logic to select the Check In date earlier than Check Out date? If the Check In date is after Check Out date, an error should be popped up saying "check in date should be earlier than checkout date"

I have used action listener but I am not able to replicate.

Comment: Check the answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10021565/how-to-show-only-date-after-the-date-of-today-in-jcalendar?noredirect=1&lq=1#answer-10023003) . Is that something you need?

Comment: Also, to check whether the check-in date is after the chcek-out date, you can try this: `if(checkInDate.after(checkOutDate)) {
    // Do your Stuff.
}`

Comment: There are several things you "could" do - you could make the check out field uneditable until the check in field is filled in, at which time you could constrain the date picker to dates after the check in date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now, How to write the logic to select the Check In date earlier than Check Out date?

Start by having a look at the [JavaDocs for `java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), you will find that it has a number of handy methods, notably [`before`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#after-java.util.Date-) and [`after`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#before-java.util.Date-).  From this you can build a simple logic check based on your needs

> If the Check In date is after Check Out date, an error should be popped up saying "check in date should be earlier than checkout date"

The most common method is to use a `JOptionPane`, take a look at [How to make dialogs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for more details

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an ActionListener to dateChooser_1

Read about ActionListeners in this tutorial:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html

Comment: I have used this, but I am not able to replicate because the variable dateChooser and dataChooser_1 belongs to different functions. So, I get error. How to bring both of them together and use them. Say if, I had the date in String format such as,  String date1 = "date 1" and String date2 = "date 2", I would have compared and written the code.

Comment: Make them a field

Comment: That is possible, but I want to use DatePicker jar file to generate the date. Is  there anyway we can do it?

Comment: Continue reading your books Sir you need to pickup some basics first

Comment: @aanshu If you have date values as `String`s, then you are doing something horribly wrong and need to seriously re-think your approach.  You should get all values into their appropriate type values, this would mean using `Date` or, preferably, `LocalDate`

Comment: Below is the code I tried:     'SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
  
  
  Date d1 = null;
  Date d2 = null;
  
  try {
    d1 = format.parse(format.format(dateChooser.getDate()));
    d2 = format.parse(format.format(dateChooser_1.getDate()));
   if(d1.after(d2)) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Check In date should be earlier than Check Out date");
   }
  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }'